# Incorrect placements of css elements (wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been playing around with wordpress plugins for a couple of hours and have managed to get most things working apart from a css-related problem that just occured.

I believe I've missed closing a div or possibly have some undeclared element present that I'm missing.

[This is the site in question.](http://norderier.com)
As you can see, it's displaying the content correctly. [This one](http://norderier.com/library/), on the other hand is definitely missing something.

I've been going through the positioning of my different elements but I just can't seem to get it all worked out correctly.

I'm guessing it's something obvious but I've got somewhat of a tunnel vision right now. Any pointers would be highly appreciated! I'm happy to share whatever code may be needed.

Comment: check this out: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnorderier.com%2Flibrary%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0 it shows you have many markup errors

Comment: If possible, try to keep everything here on stackoverflow.com so that it can help others in the future. Post the relevant parts of code and screenshots if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just from a brief scan of the html the first red flag that I saw was two elements with the same id. I would start investigations there because even if it is not causing the issue you are describing, it is still something that needs some attention.

```
<div id="primary"></div>
<aside id="primary" role="complementary"></aside>
```

Edit:
As the comment below mentions, just switch the id of the div to `content` and it fixes it.

Comment: That's it. The div should have the id **content**.